# How to place jQuery Validation text to the right of the Title instead of to the right of the Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery validation to generate a custom message if validation fails.
By default, the message is going to the right of the input field that it's validating.
I want this message to instead always go to the right of the field title.

For example, I want it to look like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/zWgbP/

I've played around with adding:

```
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
            error.insertBefore(element);    
         },
```

...but that isn't quite right since I need it to come before the break after the title "Last Name".

Is there a better way to target the field title if I surround it in a span or div and give it an id using the jQuery method I have below?

If not, is there a better method?

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#newform").validate(  

    rules: {
        lastname: {
            required: true, 
            minlength: 2            
        },

    messages: {
        lastname: {
            required: "* please fix",
            minlength: "* please fix"
        },
```

THE HTML

```
<form name="newform" id="newform" method="post" onsubmit="return OnNewButton();">

<input type='text' id='lastname' name='lastname' size='20' value = "" />

</form>
```

THE CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
#newform label.error {
color: red;
font-size: 15px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `errorPlacement` seems like the right solution, you just need to figure out the correct relationship. Your HTML doesn't include a label for the input field, so it's hard to say what it should be.

Comment: Barmar is right, check out the options page for some more info http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

Comment: Thanks: looks like the appendTo option is what I need.

$("#myform").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
     error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
   },
   debug:true
 })

Comment: Looking at docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions "

...I see the way they use "next" or "element.prev"

...is this just common jQuery/javascript terminology, or should I be looking for a fuller write up on jQuery errorPlacement to see that "prev' and "next" are the terms to use... the linked page just gives the one example, but I'd like to know all the options and possibilities for errorPlacement... searching google gives me just other examples. Not sure if there's full spec page for it somewhere.

Comment: Use `errorPlacement` for precise placement.  `next()` and `prev()` are not specific to this plugin; they are jQuery methods, so nothing wrong with using them.  Looks like you figured it out on your own, so please post your solution below as an answer and then don't forget to "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add the following errorPlacment option in my jQuery:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo('#title-' + element.attr('id'));
},
```

I then changed this:

```
Last Name<br />
```

into

```
<span id="title-lastname">Last Name</span><br />
```

The id of the filed being validated is "lastname".

Doing this appended my error message to the span before the break br perfectly.

Thanks for you help everybody.